# Forcing PyTorch Neural Net to output a specific datatype

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I am learning how to create a GAN with PyTorch 1.12 and I need the instance returned by my generator to fall into a specific feature space.

The model in my generator class looks like this:

```
self.model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(2, 16),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(16, 32),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(32, 2),
        )
```

I need every feature in the instance returned by my generator to be an unsigned integer. The noise fed into the generator fits this, but the output has decimals and some features are negative. How can I set this?

(If needed I can include more of my code but I figured this is the relevant line and wanted to keep this question short to make things easier for everyone.)

Comment: Typically you would cast and normalise your labels and do learning in the fp32 range, and then cast to unsigned int when you were finished. For example, the 0-255 uint8 range of images would be squashed to 0-1 fp32 (or -1 to 1) and the learning would happen in that space. Only in visualisation or saving of the generated images would you convert back to uint8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try clipping negative values and casting to `torch.int32`:

```py
from torch import nn
import torch


class TransformOutput(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def forward(self, x):
        return torch.clamp_min(x, min=0).to(dtype=torch.int32)


model = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(2, 16),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(16, 32),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(32, 2),
    TransformOutput(),
)

x = torch.rand(4, 2) - 0.5
out = model(x)
assert out.dtype == torch.int32
```

Comment: I like this option. Does this affect training at all? As in, does including this step in the generator model during training increase loss? My intuition is no, since the process is essentially generator -> transformation -> discriminator in a feedback loop, but I only have a partial understanding of the GAN as a whole.

Comment: There has been some research on this topic, specifically on 'Discrete GANs', but they usually do not round during training, but only for generation. Generally, training on floats seems to work better due to the continuous notion of the loss functions etc. You can try both, but literature usually suggests rounding only for usage afterwards, not during training